# No sound through DisplayPort

Tags: windows-xp, audio, hdmi, displayport, hp-elitebook

I'm trying to connect my [Elitebook 8440p](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02030597-3%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) laptop to my Samsung HDTV.  The laptop does not have a HDMI connection, but it does have DisplayPort.  I bought a [C&E TOOGOO DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002CSRFD8), and connected it with a 3 feet HDMI cable.  The video shows up fine, but there is no audio.  DisplayPort, HDMI, and the adapter all support audio.

I contacted HP tech support, who told me to update my sound drivers.  I installed the driver and rebooted.  Supposedly, I should see a "HD Audio" tab.  No luck, even after installing the driver again and rebooting.  HP closed the case.  I'm using Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 3):

I travel a lot – here is what I do:

- plug in HDMI
- turn on TV to right input etc...
- close the lid and let it go to sleep wait a few seconds
- open the lid then quickly close it
- wait for it to output video to the TV (you may need to reboot with lid closed)
- then open the lid if you need to setup screens etc.. I found the intel software left in clone mode works great! My res is 1280x720

I use a display port to HDMI dongle  but it should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this same issue recently with my Dell Latitude running an Nvidia NVS3100 mobile graphics card, using a similar adapter to a 24" HDMI Dell monitor and from researching, I found that Audio is an ***optional*** signal with Displayport 1.1a. Most hardware these days is enabled, but updated drivers are a must, which is why the support told you that. Quite rude to shut you down without giving you a link to the driver, however.

The HP forum thread below may have a solution for you, as they're using similar setups and have found working solutions. I don't have an actual solution here, I'm merely trying to be of use as I struggled to get my issue resolved recently and I know what a pain in the butt it can be!

Sources:

1. [Displayport FAQs](http://www.displayport.org/consumer/?q=content/faq)
2. [HP forum](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-PC-Sound-and-Audio/DisplayPort-on-HP-5310m-also-supports-audio/td-p/155873)

Edit:

I also just found these tips that might work for you:

On a machine with a discrete graphic card - just choose NVidia HD audio as playback device after connecting your display.
On a machine with an integrated graphic card - the trick is to go to Control Panel > Sound control panel > Right click on your TV > Select 'Set as Default Device'.  Then you should start hearing audio out from the TV speakers, and the green sound volume meter beside the TV in the Sound Control Panel should start responding to the audio you're playing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue with a HP Small Form Factor PC.

- applied all avaliable Driver Updates
- after investigatig the BIOS (search if there is a Option in the BIOS to switch from SPDIF to HD Audio Output)
- serching for an Option in Windows XP - Control Panel - Sound and Audio devices to change the Output Device to HD Audio

I decided that the Display-Port does not support Audio and connected a Male/Male Audio-Cable from the PC to the TV and connected the HDMI-Cable to the according Port (on the TV was a Audio-Input 'HDMI/PC/DVI-D AUDIO IN'  which is working together with one specific HDMI-Port)

This last step worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The HP support did try to help, but they failed to troubleshoot the problem, and ultimately gave up too soon.  Despite what HP support tells me, there is no HD Audio tab.

Thank you Crujach and Paul for your ideas.  These got me on the right path, and before too long I figured it out.

Here's what I did:

- I started at my desk.  iTunes was
  open, playing U2 through the laptop
  speakers.
- I carried the laptop (still on) to
  the living room and connected to the
  home entertainment center receiver
  through the HDMI/DisplayPort
  connection.
- I went to Control Panel / Sounds and
  Audio Devices / Audio tab / Sound
  Playback default device
- It was set to IDT Audio, and there
  was no other option available.
- I put the computer into Standby, and
  powered it back up.
- In the control panel, I could now
  choose between IDT Audio and NVIDIA
  High Definition Audio
- I chose NVIDIA High Definition Audio
  and clicked on Apply. Sound still
  came through the laptop speakers.
- I shut down iTunes, restarted it, and
  now it worked correctly.

The signal comes through DisplayPort, through the DisplayPort/HDMI adapter, through the HDMI cable to the home entertainment receiver, and out the surround-sound speakers.

To summarize:

1. Turn off your application (iTunes, internet browser)
2. Put computer on Standby
3. TV and receiver should be ON
4. Connect to TV or receiver via HDMI cable (and DisplayPort-HDMI adapter)
5. Come out of standby (or restart)
6. Control Panel / Sounds and Audio Devices / Audio tab / Sound Playback default device
7. Select NVIDIA High Definition Audio and click on Apply
8. Open your application (iTunes, internet browser)
9. Make sure sound on laptop is turned to maximum and not muted

Comment: Good job figuring it out, that makes sense. I did find a small app that automatically switches audio inputs, you might try it. The author has said he believes it to work in XP: http://coastalaudiochanger.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by reloading HD sound devices

1. Launch device manager
2. Select sound video and game controller
3. Uninstall HD sound device(s)
4. scan for new hardware

Answer (score 0):

I came here though a google query "displayport sound gone", and wanted to leave a solution that worked for me. After running a driver update, for some reason the playback device was disabled under the device manager. Simply re-enabling it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same 8540p laptop and resolved this issue by downgrading the Nvidia drivers.

[This is the driver I used.](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp55001-55500/sp55192.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a shorter HDMI Cable. I just solved an issue where my TV wasn't showing up as an audio device in windows. I was using a displayport -> HDMI adapter with a 25' cable. Swapped to a shorter 5' cable and now it works perfect. Must be something about how the tv reports itself to the computer can't make it down that long of a cable AND an adapter. Hope this helps some weary googling troubleshooters out there. Cheers!